# air-lld: error: symbol(s) not found for target 'air64-apple-ios12.0.0' after update xcode to xcode 12

Tags: xcode, metal

here is the error:

Undefined symbol(s) for architecture 'air64':_Z6dnoiseDv2_fPU9MTLdeviceKi', referenced from:_Z9curlNoiseDv2_fhffPU9MTLdeviceKi in nxNoise.air
air-lld: error: symbol(s) not found for target 'air64-apple-ios12.0.0'
metal: error: air-lld command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: and what are you doing?

Comment: I really dont know!

Comment: Happens to all my Projects where I use metal code - since I upgraded to Xcode 12 - No solution yet

Comment: Late, but for me, the problem was due to some functions which were declared in header files but not implemented inside .m files. remove that function's declarations solved my problem.

Comment: But the missing symbols were in the Metal APIs. What does that have to do with .m files? Looks like you were using a `noise` function?

Answer (score 5):

Find the `Other Metal Compiler Flags` option in the project target `Build Settings` and add `-fcikernel` value to that flag in the `Metal Compiler` and `Metal Linker` section of Build Settings.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Late but maybe useful for someone:
The problem was due to some functions which were declared in header files but not implemented inside .m files. remove that function's declarations solved my problem.